# Does PokerSnowie have any weaknesses in its game? If so, what are they?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-tools, software, training

I'm using PokerSnowie to help improve my game but have seen a few comments on other sites suggesting that it compares poorly with genuine solvers that find the Nash equilibrium strategy. I currently play exploitative strategies at micro-stakes, and will continue to do so against the weaker players, but against the better players I need to learn things like the correct betting frequencies on different boards and which blockers enable the best bluffs etc.

I'm confident that Snowie will improve these aspects of my game, but I want to be aware of any weaknesses it has, if any, so that once I graduate to higher stakes I don't show up with any major flaws.

Does PokerSnowie make mistakes? If so, what situations does it make them in and how do they compare to optimal play?

Answer (score 0):

Like any tool or software, PokerSnowie has its limitations and potential areas where it may not perfectly align with the absolute GTO approach. PokerSnowie is not a solver in the traditional sense. True solvers, like PioSolver or GTO+, work by calculating the Nash Equilibrium for specific situations. PokerSnowie, on the other hand, is based on AI that's been trained on vast amounts of data but may not always reach true Nash Equilibrium in every situation.